# Can someone help me proving this statement about fundamental groups and coverings?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

In the lecture we had the following statement. Since our Prof. said it is trivial we didn't proved it, but since I want to get used with the notations and methods I would like to prove it. So the statement is the following.

> Let $p:Y\rightarrow X$ is a covering such that $p(y)=x$. Then if $\sigma$ is a loop at $x$ and $\sigma^+$ is the unique lifting of $\sigma$ to a path startign at $y$ then $\sigma^+$ ends at $y$ iff $[\sigma]\in p_*\left(\Pi_1(Y,y)\right)$ where we define $$p_*:\Pi(Y,y)\rightarrow \Pi(X,x);\quad[\sigma]\mapsto [p\circ \sigma]$$

Now my Idea was the following:

$\Rightarrow$ Let us assume that $\sigma^+$ ends at $y$ so it is a loop in $Y$ based at $y$ then by the lifting property and by uniqness
$$\sigma=p\circ \sigma^+\\
\implies [\sigma]=[p\circ \sigma^+]\\\iff [\sigma]\in p_*(\Pi(Y,y))$$
$\Leftarrow$ Let us assume here that $[\sigma]\in p_*(\Pi(Y,y))$, this means that $[\sigma]=[p\circ \psi]$ for some loop $\psi$ based at $y$. Now we can take $\psi=\sigma^+$ and thus we get $[\sigma]=[p\circ \sigma^+]$. But in my opinion this means that $\sigma$ is homotopic to $p\circ \sigma^+$ with fixed endpoints. But then how can I say that $\sigma^+$ ends at y?

And is the rest $\Rightarrow$ this implication so correct?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the $\Leftarrow$ implication, note that since $\sigma$ and $p\circ\psi$ are homotopic, and since $\sigma^+$ and $\psi$ have the same initial points, $\sigma^+$ and $\psi$ are homotopic too. But $\psi$ is a loop. Therefore, $\sigma^+$ is a loop too.

Comment: So the other direction is correct right?

But I mean $\psi$ is only a lifting of $\sigma$ if $\sigma=p\circ \psi$ but we only know that  $[\sigma]=[p\circ \psi]$ how can we conclude then

Comment: Nice point. I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Yes makes much more sense, I only think about why we can say that two paths with the same initial points are homotopic if both endpoints are fixed. Because we only know the initial and endpoint of $\psi$  form $\sigma^+$ we only know the initial point at the beginning.

Comment: Let $H\colon[0,1]\times[0,1]\longrightarrow Y$ be a homotopy between $\sigma^+$ and $\psi$. Then the $H(\{1\}\times[0,1])$ is a connected subset of $p^{-1}(\{x\})$. But this is a discrete set (since $p$ is a covering) to which $y$ belongs (it is equal to $H(1,1)$). So, $\sigma^+(1)=H(0,1)=y$.

Comment: ah perfect thanks!